# How to make this eav query horizontal

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

I want to choose from below table records that have (`property_id=18 and property_value=78) and (property_id=19 and property_value=113)` that in this table results record with `id = 12`.

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD6ng.jpg) to image of table.

Here is my MySQL query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Product`.* , ProductMeta.property_id, ProductMeta.property_value
FROM `shop_products` AS `Product`
LEFT JOIN `shop_categories` AS `Category` ON (`Product`.`category_id` = `Category`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `shop_product_metas` AS `ProductMeta` ON (`Product`.`id` = `ProductMeta`.`product_id`)  
WHERE 
        `Product`.`category_id` = (26) 
        AND 
        (`Product`.`price` * (1 - (`Product`.`off`/100)) ) >= '100' 
        AND 
        (`Product`.`price` * (1 - (`Product`.`off`/100)) ) <= '5000000' 
        AND 
        (
                (
                 ((`ProductMeta`.`property_id` = 18) AND (`ProductMeta`.`property_value` = '77'))
                 OR 
                 ((`ProductMeta`.`property_id` = 18) AND (`ProductMeta`.`property_value` = '78'))
                )
                AND 
                ((`ProductMeta`.`property_id` = 19) AND (`ProductMeta`.`property_value` = '113'))
      )
```

Comment: what is the problem with your query?

Comment: The problem is that one record can't be with (property_id=18 and property_value=77) and in the same time with (property_id=19 and property_value=113) so the result always is empty.imagine property_id=18 is for color of products and property_id=19 is for size so I want to choose all the products that have for example (color red or color green) and size 40. Thanks.